# how to knockout for svg text element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, svg

I'm using knockout-2.2.1.js in my application and i'm also using svg elements. I'm creating application svg with knockout, its working fine for other svg elements like rect,circle,line,.. ect, except text. I need to update the text of the svg text on dynamically data change.
Here is the code which i used

```
<text  x="18px" y="-5px" fill="black" style="font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;" data-bind:\"attr:{ text: knockoutObject.data1()>80?'Tested Ok':'Tested Failed' }\"></text>
```

How it can be possible and Is there any way to use knockout for svg text elements?

Any suggestions should be appreciated!..

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data-bind=`. Also why do you use a `attr` binding instead of plain `text`? See: http://jsfiddle.net/rcvkL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use knockout with SVG.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red" data-bind="text: text"></text>
</svg>

<label>width: <input type='text' data-bind="value: text, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></label>
```

and JS:

```
function VM(){
    this.text = ko.observable('I love SVG');
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Also the funny escape characters in your markup is not going to help you at all.